# Java Hibernate session delete of object

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm really struggling with hibernate sessions, I never have the result I expect when making a query on a modified session object. I think all my problems are related. The last one is the following :

```
final Session iSession = AbstractDAO.getSessionFactory().openSession();
try {
    iSession.beginTransaction();
    MyObject iObject = DAOMyObject.getInstance().get(iSession,ObjectId);
    iObject.setQuantity(0); //previously the quantity was different from zero
    DAOMyObject.getInstance().update(iSession,iObject);
    DAOMyObject.getInstance().deleteObjectWithZeroQuantities(iSession);
    iSession.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (final Exception aException) {
    iSession.getTransaction().rollback();
    logger.error(aException.getMessage(), aException);
    throw aException;
} finally {
    iSession.close();
}
```

What I'm not getting is why the object is not deleted, since I'm modified it in the session, the query making the delete should find it. I had the same problem with creating an object with an incremental id in a session, then creating another one in the same session before the commit, with a `select max(id)+1`. But the session gets me the same number of id every time.

Comment: Please inline the code executed by your `DAOMyObject` class. It's hard to guess what's hidden behind those custom methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that inside `DAOMyObject.getInstance().deleteObjectWithZeroQuantities(iSession)` you make a query that *hits the database*. However, in the DB your `iObject.getQuantity()` is still `!=0`, so it isn't deleted.

**Why does your query hit the DB instead of using the `iObject` instance cached in the `Session`?**

That's because the query has to retrieve *all entities* for which `quantity != 0`, and you do not have all of them cached. `Session`'s first level cache is typically used when you retrieve entities *by ID*, with queries of the form `select * from MyEntity where id=123456`. Adding further criteria to the `where` clause of the query forces Hibernate to hit the DB.

Note that the same happens whether the criteria is part of a `select` query or part of `update`/`delete`. Hibernate still has to hit the DB and `iObject` will be deleted.

**So how to get around it?**

1. Make two transactions. The first will change `iObject`'s quantity. The second will delete all entities with zero quantities.
2. If you have to make both operations in the same transaction, you can just delete `iObject` explicitly before/after deleting all other zero-quantity entities. Remember that you know its ID.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>and even if you do, Hibernate cannot know it as some other `Session` might have just inserted new entities that the query should also select</sub>

**Edit:**

Another option is to `session.flush()` the change of `iObject`'s quantity... And actually I think that *this* is the problem. Inside `DAOMyObject.getInstance().update(iSession,iObject)`, after changing the quantity and calling `iSession.save()`, you should call `iSession.flush()`. That would write the change to the DB so that it is visible to consequent queries that hit it. **And this is the right way to do it.**

Comment: Thanks ! Makes more sense now. I just thought hibernate would make a difference between what it already has in the session and what it needs to retrieve from the DB instead of getting everything from the DB since informations in the session is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a `session.flush()`.

Your object changes are only in memory, and only until the flush will they be persistent in the DB. Alternatively, you can set the `FlushMode` to `COMMIT`, and every commit will also flush. I recommend manually flushing every time, though.

Comment: Flush mode is AUTO by default, and a flush will be made automatically before each commit, and before each query which might be affected by the pending modifications. Flushing manually is, most of the time, a bad idea. BTW, flushing doesn't synchronize the JDBS connection's state, whatever that might mean.